# Permanently disable audio devices even when reconnected

Tags: laptop, audio, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with the following devices (image doctored; I digitally stitched the bottom on to show all devices) at work:

[image]

Normally I disable the DisplayPort audio devices and use a bluetooth headset for audio, for the most part it works well (I have two U3014 monitors..

Occasionally when I connect the monitors to the ports, they become re-enabled (as shown in the screen) and set as the default audio device. This doesn't happen always, but enough to start getting old.

This doesn't happen all the time however - most of the time it seems to be fine. I suspect it has something to down with the whether I've rebooted or the sequence in which I suspended and disconnected from my home monitors (where it also happens).

Does anybody know if there is a way to make HDMI devices permanently disabled?

Setup is a Metabox (Clevo) P775DM3-G . Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 14393)

Comment: If you don't find a way to prevent it, you could maybe use [Audio Switcher](https://audioswit.ch/er) to hot key your preferred output so you can switch back in a second.

Comment: @Tetsujin interesting! thanks for bringing this to my attention

Comment: +1 would like to see a solution for this, it's such a PITA